# List of geometries for a GEE function across their indexes

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm new in programming
I'm trying to write a function which lets me call one after another all my geometries from the list.
But I'm not sure if it's possible to use their indexes or I need to look for another way.

Link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/0c20388e574ebea0255137573fff3e7b

Here is the code:

```
var municipi = ee.FeatureCollection("users/AnastasiiaKhimchenko/Municipi_Roma"),
    mod = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MYD11A2");

//Map.addLayer(municipi, {color: 'green'}, 'Municipi di Roma');

var day = mod.filterDate('2020-01-01', '2021-01-01')
             .filter(ee.Filter.dayOfYear(152, 243))
             .filterBounds(municipi)
             .select('LST_Day_1km')
             .median()
             .multiply(0.02)
             .subtract(273.15);
             
// Map.addLayer(day, {
//   min: 25, max: 40, palette: ['blue', 'limegreen', 'yellow', 'darkorange', 'red']
// }, 'Municipi LST Modis Day');             


var m1 = (municipi.filter(ee.Filter.equals('municipio', '1')));
var m2 = (municipi.filter(ee.Filter.equals('municipio', '2')));
var m3 = (municipi.filter(ee.Filter.equals('municipio', '3')));


var municipiList = ee.List([m1, m2, m3]);
municipiList.map(function(i) {
  
for(var index = 0; index <=2; index++){
  if (municipiList[index] <=2) {

Map.addLayer(day.clip(municipiList[index]), {min: 25, max: 40, palette: ['blue', 'limegreen', 'yellow', 'darkorange', 'red']},
'Municipio' + index)}}})
```

Comment: Could you please add the code to the question body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the function that you want to call is a client-side function (e.g. `Map.addLayer`) and will operate on images, I recommend the following:

1. Transform your image collection to a list.
2. Prepare a function that will call the `.get(index)` method from that list. Make sure that you cast the ee Object that you get with the correct type (e.g. ee.Image()).
3. Prepare a list of indices that you will need.
4. Map the (client-side) function to the list of indices.

In this specific example, it looks like what you want to achieve is displaying N layers (one for each feature in your `municipi` table), consisting of the image `day` clipped to the given feature.

I don't know how many features you have (I don't have access to your asset), but depending on how many you have, you might want to explore other options.

Option 1: instead of N layers, simply make 1 layer consisting of the image `day` clipped to the feature collection:

```js
// Add the image clipped to the "municipi" feature collection:
Map.addLayer(day.clip(municipi), {min: 25, max: 40, palette: ['blue', 'limegreen', 'yellow', 'darkorange', 'red']}, "Image clipped to municipi")
```

Option 2: prepare a image collection where each image is clipped to one feature of `municipi`, then add the image collection to the Map:

```js
// For each feature in "municipi", add one layer consisting of the clipped image:
// First make it an image collection:
function clip_image_to_feature(feature){
  return day.clip(feature)
}
var clipped_image_collection=ee.ImageCollection(municipi.map(clip_image_to_feature))


Map.addLayer(clipped_image_collection,
{min: 25, max: 40, palette: ['blue', 'limegreen', 'yellow', 'darkorange', 'red']},
"The same, but as an image collection.") // this should look exactly the same as our previous Map.addLayer()
```

Of course, this layer should look identical as the previous one.

Option 3: if you really want to have them as separate layers, then we can do it based on the instructions given above:

```js
/* If you really want them as separate layers, we can 
1. Get the size of the img collection
2. Transform the img collection to a list.
3. Make a function to add one image with a given index (valid from 0 to nImages-1)
4. Call the function for each index. 
*/
var nImages = clipped_image_collection.size();
var img_list = clipped_image_collection.toList(nImages);

function addImgIndexToMap(index){
  // Client-side function to call Map.addLayer
  var image = ee.Image(img_list.get(index)); 
  Map.addLayer(image, 
  {min: 25, max: 40, palette: ['blue', 'limegreen', 'yellow', 'darkorange', 'red']},
  "Image with index "+index
  )
}

var img_indices = ee.List.sequence(0,nImages.subtract(1)).getInfo();  //[0,1,...,nImages-1]
img_indices.map(addImgIndexToMap); // Call the function for each index.
```

Here's a full example with the three options above: https://code.earthengine.google.com/a9e82453a6972e4050a1c08f158ab6d6

Note that I had to draw another `municipi2` feature collection (simply 4 rectangles) and defined `municipi=municipi2` in the first line, because I do not have access to your asset.

Comment: Thank you! Have a good Easter! :)